# Adding DateTime to ListView?

Tags: c#, arrays, datetime, listview

How can I add a DateTime value along with 2 string values into a ListView?
I've tried...

```
String[] row = { Time.Value.ToString(), "Example Text", "Example Text"};
listView1.Items.AddRange(row);
```

but I get conversion errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you're question has anything specifically to do with a ListView. It sounds like you just need to know how to extract the time from a DateTime value into a string.

Use the [DateTime.ToString(String) method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa326721%28VS.71%29.aspx) with the "T" standard format ([MSDN standard DateTime formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hc4ky857%28VS.71%29.aspx)):

```
Time.Value.ToString("T")
```

That would return the following for en-us:

> 3:51:24 PM

Answer (score 0):

Is this a Windows Forms ListView? If so, you want to add ListViewItem's to it. ListViewItem can take an array of strings to represent its columns.

[Example on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.aspx)

Comment: Oh, I've figured out how to add, but now I want it so that it only shows the time. Is that possible? Currently, it shows the Date and Time.

Comment: Okay... I've figured out how to show only time by using TimeSpan, but now it shows 00:00:00. How can I change TimeSpan to a 12hour format (00:00 AM)?

Comment: A timespan is not a time. There's no such thing as a 12hour format timespan.

Comment: Yeah, I kinda figured that out too late.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just getting started with a ListView, you can save yourself a *lot* of pain and trouble by using [ObjectListView](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/objectlistview.aspx) -- an open source wrapper around .NET WinForms ListView. It makes working with a ListView much easier as well as solving some very annoying problems that you will otherwise encounter.

For example, it knows how to handle dates, including sorting, grouping and editing.

In another question, you asked about saving and restoring the state of the ListView. ObjectListView has methods to do those tasks as well.

Save yourself pain now -- use ObjectListView :)